# How to define input_shape for BiDirectional layer of a RNN for time series

Tags: python, input, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to build a RNN for time series prediction, but I can't seem to figure out how to specify the input_shape for the Bidirectional layer (input_shape needs to be input_shape(win_sz, 3)). Any help would be really appreciated. :)

I'm using Keras version 2.x

**my code:**

```
   model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
          tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
          tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation = 'sigmoid', return_sequences=False, input_shape=(None))),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])

    lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lambda epoch: 1e-8 * 10**(epoch/20))

    sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-8, momentum=.91, clipvalue=0.5)
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
             optimizer=sgd,
             metrics=['mse'])
```

Comment: What happens if you just put that shape in?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I think you should read a little bit more about how time-series inputs look like in Keras. But to help you along the way, let me demonstrate how I might use your model in an toy example.

But before diving straight into the example, let me explain what a time-series input is.

### Time series input

A time series input is (typically) a 3D input which has the following dimensions.

- Batch dimension - number of samples in a batch
- Time dimension - represents the temporal aspect of your data (e.g. number of days)
- Input dimension - number of feature sin a single input and a single timestep

So the input is a tensor of size `(batch size, timesteps, input size)`. Let's now go to the example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

b_size = 5
timesteps = 30
in_size = 10
```

So using these values, I can create a dummy input (5, 30, 10) and a dummy output (5, 1).

```
dummy_in = np.random.normal(size=(b_size, timesteps, in_size))
dummy_out = np.random.normal(size=(b_size, 1))
```

### Defining the input shape

So when defining the input shape, you **only** define the time dimension and the input dimension. You leave the batch dimension out as that will be handled by Keras. So your `input_shape=(30, 10)`

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
          tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
          tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation = 'sigmoid', return_sequences=False, input_shape=(timesteps, in_size))),
          tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])

lr_schedule = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lambda epoch: 1e-8 * 10**(epoch/20))

sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-8, momentum=.91, clipvalue=0.5)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
          optimizer=sgd,
          metrics=['mse'])
```

Now you can try this model with the toy data above.

```
model.fit(dummy_in, dummy_out)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's very helpful. However, I keep running into the same problem. When I use data to " forecast = model.predict(x_valid) " I keep getting this error: 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected bidirectional_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (526, 3).

Comment: Again, you're not providing a 3D input. Your input x_valid needs to be a (batch size , time steps , input size ) tensor.